# Resonance modes of a cubic box of water which we shake

Tags: waves, water, simulations, fluid-dynamics

I don't know hydrodynamics, but I wonder how one would compute resonance modes of a cubic box of water which we shake. I believe the waves would directly depend on the height of water and the width and length of the box. Is it a bit like a waveguide for electodynamics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is a bit like waveguide for electrodynamics. You've got [absolutely the same equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_wave_theory#Mathematical_formulation_of_the_wave_motion). The difference is in boundary conditions -- instead of [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) you've got to use [Neumann boundary conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition).

[image]

While of course it works only if you are able no neglect all the non-linear effects -- your waves are low enough.

Comment: For the smaller wavelengths surface tension also comes into play.

Comment: Well, yes. But you still can linearise this.

Comment: Kosttya, yes you can. The main effect will be that the frequencies versus wavelength plot will have different slopes at short versus long wavelengths.

Comment: Well, of course. But it is irrelevant to my discussion. We are dealing with Laplace equation -- check the reference. There is no time and therefore no frequencies.